# Unexpected HashSet equals behavior

Tags: java, equals, hashset

Here is a snippet where the strange behavior occurs in Java 8 :

```
 @Test
    public void test() {
        DummyPojo dummyPojo1 = DummyPojo.of("1", "A");
        DummyPojo dummyPojo2 = DummyPojo.of("2", "B");

        Set<DummyPojo> set1 = new HashSet<>();
        set1.add(dummyPojo1);

        Set<DummyPojo> set2 = new HashSet<>();
        set2.add(dummyPojo2);

        System.out.println("dummyPojo1 == dummyPojo2 should be false = " + (dummyPojo1.equals(dummyPojo2)));
        System.out.println("set1 == set2             should be false = " + (set1.equals(set2)));

        dummyPojo1.setAttribute1(dummyPojo2.getAttribute1());
        dummyPojo1.setAttribute2(dummyPojo2.getAttribute2());

        System.out.println("dummyPojo1 == dummyPojo2 should be true  = " + (dummyPojo1.equals(dummyPojo2)));
        System.out.println("set1 == set2             should be true  = " + (set1.equals(set2)));//WRONG
        System.out.println("set2 == set1             should be true  = " + (set2.equals(set1)));//Breaking of Object#equals symmetry
    }

    @Data
    public static class DummyPojo {
        private String attribute1;
        private String attribute2;

        public static DummyPojo of(String attribute1, String attribute2) {
            DummyPojo dummyPojo = new DummyPojo();
            dummyPojo.attribute1 = attribute1;
            dummyPojo.attribute2 = attribute2;
            return dummyPojo;
        }
    }
```

And here the result :

```
dummyPojo1 == dummyPojo2 should be false = false
set1 == set2             should be false = false
dummyPojo1 == dummyPojo2 should be true  = true
set1 == set2             should be true  = false
set2 == set1             should be true  = true
```

Modifying an element of a set **after** insertion can have this behavior (please note that the lombok annotation `@Data` does implement equals and hashcode methods).
The reason is that when adding the element in the set, it will insert it in the table of node of the hashMap backing the map. To do so it compute the index via the hashcode.

```
 final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent,
                   boolean evict) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
        if ((tab = table) == null || (n = tab.length) == 0)
            n = (tab = resize()).length;
        if ((p = tab[i = (n - 1) & hash]) == null) //<-- HERE table[15 & hashcode] when first element
            tab[i] = newNode(hash, key, value, null);
        .
        .
        .
}
```

However, when it's checking if it contains the element, it will assume that the position in the table is the same :

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
        Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
        if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
            (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {//<-- HERE table[15 & hashcode]
        .
        .
        .
}
```

However, as the element in this example is not immutable, the hashcode has changed between the insertion and the contains. So, even so the element are equals according to their equals method, and so the sets contains the same element, the equals on the sets returns an unexpected value.

Moreover, as shown here, it's breaking the symmetry of equals as stated in the javadoc of Object#equals :

> It is *symmetric*: for any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` should return `true` **if and only if** `y.equals(x)` returns `true`.

There is a java bug reporting it : https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6579200

The answer is :

> The contract of HashSet and HashMap does not allow for result of hashCode() to change during tenure of an object in the collection nor may the set of objects to which it is equal change during the tenure.

However, I **did not find** it stated in the javadoc of either HashMap or HashSet.
A person not aware of this behavior might give too much trust in it and have production issue very difficult to understand.
What I found more problematic is the break in the Object contract as frameworks may rely on it.

Is it planned to modify, if not the implementation, at least the javadoc to specify it more clearly ?

Answer (score 4):

It's documented in [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html):

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

and [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

The mutable value problem affects other map/set implementations too (for example `TreeMap`/`TreeSet`).

This isn't really a question of implementation: there is simply no language mechanism (in general) for a collection (or indeed a plain reference) to know if the referred objects have changed.

Answer (score 0):

Andy Turner's answer is the correct one. I think it's worth adding that the prohibition on changing *"the value of an object ... in a manner that affects equals comparisons"* imposes an implicit prohibition on the `hashCode` method, of which [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) say:

> Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.

These two constraints together imply that the behaviour of any `Map` or `Set` (not just these implementations) is undefined if a map key or set element has a varying `hashCode` over its lifetime.

However, inferring this does require looking at the docs for `Map` and `Object` when the class you're using is `HashMap`; and it requires connecting these dots together. Arguably, a more specific warning about `hashCode` should appear in the docs for `HashMap` and `HashSet` (as well as other classes like `ConcurrentHashMap` and `LinkedHashMap`). To address your actual question, *"Is it planned to modify ... the javadoc to specify it more clearly?"*, I was not able to find any open bug reports making this request, so you may wish to submit your own.

Note that your statement about this *"breaking the symmetry of equals"* is not correct; the unexpected behaviour occurs because when the object can't be looked up using its new `hashCode`, it never gets compared for equality anyway.